# org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException:User: is not allowed to impersonate

Tags: windows, hadoop, hive, hdfs, thrift

I have been successful mostly in running hadoop and hive on Windows natively (without cygwin).

For Hive, all I did was that I unzipped the official zip file and set the HIVE_HOME and PATH. Also, I set the hive-site.xml as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll</name>
        <value>true</value>
        <description>creates necessary schema on a startup if one doesn't exist. set this to false, after creating it once</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I am able to run `hive`. Seemingly, thrift server is also running using `hive --service thriftserver2`.

But when I try to connect to hive using jdbc from my web app, with my current Windows user-name and password, it gives following error:

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException:User: anurag.kalia is not allowed to impersonate anurag.kalia

Note: there is no folder named "/home/anurag.kalia" on hdfs.
Also, I have added following in hadoop core-site.xml after some Google searches:

```
<property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.anurag.kalia.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.anurag.kalia.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
```

But this is still not working. Is there any way for hive to successfully impersonate?

Comment: does your username have a `.` in between?

Comment: @franklinsijo yes. Is that a problem? How can I circumvent my windows username?

Answer (score 0):

The proxyuser properties (`hadoop.proxyuser.$superuser.groups`, `hadoop.proxyuser.$superuser.hosts`) added to `core-site.xml` does not work if there is a `.` in `$superuser`.

Without proxyuser config properties, impersonation will not be possible. A Jira [HADOOP-7050](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7050) is still open for this issue.